# How can i capture the failed items only from list of items and display output

Tags: ansible

I am trying to write Ansible to list only the failed commands from the list of commands

here is the code

```yaml
---
- name: Verify sudo access
  become: true
  become_user: "{{ install_user }}"
  shell: sudo -l | grep "{{ item }}"
  register: systemctl_result
  loop:
    - /usr/bin/mv
    - /usr/bin/olcenctl
    - /usr/bin/yum
  when: ansible_hostname in groups['operator']
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Print result
  debug:
   var: systemctl_result['results']
```

`/usr/bin/yum` is not in `sudo` list and it fails and I want to capture only the failed command in the output.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74021516/edit) and fix the formatting. While you're there, edit your question to show what your experience is versus what you wish was happening. We can't read your mind

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be simplified. The `become, sudo, ...` stuff is not relevant. What you want is to list failed items in the iteration. Use `ignore_errors: true` to take care of `rc: 1` returned by failed *grep*. For example,

```yaml
    - shell: "echo ABC | grep {{ item }}"
      register: out
      ignore_errors: true
      loop:
        - A
        - B
        - X
```

Then, put the below declaration into the *vars*

```yaml
    failed_items: "{{ out.results|
                      selectattr('failed')|
                      map(attribute='item')|
                      list }}"
```

gives what you want

```yaml
failed_items:
  - X
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    failed_items: "{{ out.results|
                      selectattr('failed')|
                      map(attribute='item')|
                      list }}"

  tasks:

    - shell: "echo ABC | grep {{ item }}"
      register: out
      ignore_errors: true
      loop:
        - A
        - B
        - X

    - debug:
        var: failed_items
```

Comment: I have to use the code in playbook , i tried to change var to set_facts but fails. sorry new to ansible world

Comment: No problem. [edit] your question and make it [mre].

Comment: i am using roles